# License Missing or Expired Pentaho after Reinstalling

Tags: analytics, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I installed the Pentaho server yesterday and had to reinstall it due to some modifications done by me. Now after reinstallation it when I try to log in to User Console it says like License files are missing or Expired. Expiration can't happen since I download it and installed it yesterday.

[Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMtSE.png)

[License files missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWBUv.png)

Comment: As i suggested yesterday this is community forum,people might not be able to answer enterprise tool related issue.
i will suggest to start working with community tool.
https://community.hitachivantara.com/community/products-and-solutions/pentaho

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Entrerise Edition licence then you have the great privilege of asking questions on the [Pentaho Zendesk](https://support.pentaho.com/hc/en-us).

Which does not mean you receive an answer which is understandable. Except for licensing issues.